# Local GeoJSON file with Mapbox

Tags: ajax, mapbox, geojson

I'm trying to load a local file to MapBox getting error messages:
`ERROR parsererror No conversion from text to geojson` from ajax function and
`Error {message: "Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object."}` for evented.js

Features are structured are like this:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "score": 0.77, "pokemon": "Squirtle", "color": "#42b9f5" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2.768403197476528, 39.806888683241638 ] } }
```

I'm creating geoJSON file with Python, http://geojson.io load it just fine without any errors I suppose is something about my Ajax request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY_TOKEN';

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
    });

    map.on('style.load', function() {
        map.addSource("pokemons", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    file: "../data_wrangling/points.geojson",
                    dataType: "geojson",
                    success: function(data) {
                        return data;
                    },  
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('ERROR', textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                })
        })
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an ajax object to as your data which is not supported. Try to fetch the data first before passing it in `.addSource`. [This demo](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/9104#issuecomment-565598143) may be helpful.

Alternatively, since your geojson is [stored at an URL](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/working-with-large-geojson-data/#store-geojson-at-url), you can pass that url instead of the ajax object/promise.